# Query to find differences in same table

Tags: mysql

So I am running into a problem with getting the right data from my query.

I have the following table (Person):

```
Name  |       xpath        |   value
Derek |  /body/torso/arm   |   left
Derek |  /body/torso/arm   |   right
Derek |  /body/torso/neck  |   Head
Ron   |  /body/torso/neck  |   Head
Ron   |  /body/torso/arm   |   left
```

So basically the query results i was trying to get were to show the differences (whats missing between the two people).

```
results:
Name1 |       xpath1       |   value1   | Name2  |   xpath2         |   value2
Derek |  /body/torso/arm   |   right    | Ron    |    NULL          |   NULL
```

I would even be fine with getting the following back as well

```
results:
Name1 |       xpath1       |   value1   | Name2  |   xpath2         |   value2
Derek |  /body/torso/arm   |   right    | Ron    |    NULL          |   NULL
Derek |  /body/torso/arm   |   left     | Ron    | /body/torso/arm  |   left  
Derek |  /body/torso/neck  |   Head     | Ron    | /body/torso/neck |   Head
```

The query i was using was:

```
SELECT P.Name , P.xpath, P.value, P1.Name, P2.xpath, P3.value
FROM Person as P
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Person as P2 ON P.xpath = P2.xpath
WHERE
         P.Name = "Derek"
    AND  P2.Name = "Ron"
```

The results I keep getting no matter what i try is basically the overlapping data but never what i am actually looking for, seems I am missing something simple or just plainly doing it wrong. Any suggestions? Ultimately i am going to run this in a SPROC but it would be nice to be able to handle multiple names not just 2, but if i had, Derek,Ron,John,Dawn, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
SELECT    a.Name  AS Name1,
          a.xpath AS xpath1,
          a.value AS value1,
          'Ron'   AS Name2,
          b.xpath AS xpath2,
          b.value AS value2
FROM      Person a
LEFT JOIN Person b ON b.Name = 'Ron'
                  AND a.xpath = b.xpath 
                  AND a.value = b.value
WHERE     a.Name = 'Derek' AND
          b.Name IS NULL
```

---

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f773/8)

---

If you wanted to compare Derek to multiple names, you can do a `CROSS JOIN` of all names to compare to (so that the names can appear in the result set), and `LEFT JOIN` the same table using `xpath`, `value`, and also the names specified in the `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT     a.Name  AS Name1,
           a.xpath AS xpath1,
           a.value AS value1,
           b.Name  AS Name2,
           c.xpath AS xpath2,
           c.value AS value2
FROM       Person a
CROSS JOIN (
           SELECT 'Ron' AS Name UNION ALL
           SELECT 'John'        UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Charles'     UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Aaron'
           ) b
LEFT JOIN  Person c ON b.Name  = c.Name 
                   AND a.xpath = c.xpath
                   AND a.value = c.value
WHERE      a.Name = 'Derek' AND
           c.Name IS NULL
```

---

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1407/2)

---

And if you wanted to have multiple names on the left side of the comparison (not just "Derek"), just change

```
a.Name = 'Derek'
```

to

```
a.Name <> b.Name
```

in the above query.

---

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1407/3)

---

**EDIT**: Just to take it even further:

Compare all names to all names:

```
SELECT     a.Name  AS Name1,
           a.xpath AS xpath1,
           a.value AS value1,
           b.Name  AS Name2,
           c.xpath AS xpath2,
           c.value AS value2
FROM       Person a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Person) b
LEFT JOIN  Person c ON b.Name  = c.Name 
                   AND a.xpath = c.xpath
                   AND a.value = c.value
WHERE      a.Name <> b.Name AND 
           c.Name IS NULL
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I also never knew about the SQLFiddle website. very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the EXCEPT union:

```
WITH tbl (name, xpath, value) as
    (values
        ('Derek','/body/torso/arm','left'),
        ('Derek','/body/torso/arm','right'),
        ('Derek','/body/torso/neck','Head'),
        ('Ron','/body/torso/neck','Head'),
        ('Ron','/body/torso/arm','left')
    )
SELECT xpath, value 
FROM tbl 
WHERE name = 'Derek'
    EXCEPT
        SELECT xpath, value 
        FROM tbl 
        WHERE name = 'Ron'
```